# How to break this recursive loop once I reach the last letter in my python code?

Tags: python

I would like to break the recursive loop once I reach the last letter of new. How can I do this?

Diction is a dictionary. The idea here is that I get a word there is an example below and I shrink it by matching the [i:i+1] positions of the word string with the dictionary until it gets down to one letter.

```
def eval(word):
    diction = {
        'br': 'y',
        'rb': 'y',
        'by': 'r',
        'yb': 'r',
        'yr': 'b',
        'ry': 'b',
        'bb': 'b',
        'yy': 'y',
        'rr': 'r',
    }
    new = ''
    i = 0
    while i < len(word) - 1:
        key1 = word[i:i + 2]
        i += 1
        new += diction[key1]
    return eval(new)


word = 'brybbr'
print(eval(word))
```

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have removed them both for the time being.

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: As a further aside, probably don't give your function a name which shadows a built-in function.

Comment: Don't use recursion for something that could be done just as well with a loop. `while len(word) > 1: ...; word = new`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the end condition.

In this code, I added a condition `if len(new)==1:` to finish the unlimited resursive calls.

In addition, I also added `print(new)` inside the `eval()` instead `print(eval(word))` so that it can print `new` with each calling of `eval()`.

```py
def eval(word):
    diction = {
        'br': 'y',
        'rb': 'y',
        'by': 'r',
        'yb': 'r',
        'yr': 'b',
        'ry': 'b',
        'bb': 'b',
        'yy': 'y',
        'rr': 'r',
    }
    new = ''
    i = 0
    while i < (len(word) - 1):
        key1 = word[i:i + 2]
        i += 1
        new += diction[key1]
    print(new) # to print new for every `eval()` calling.
    if len(new)==1: # to stop endless resursive calling.
        return None
    else:
        return eval(new)


word = 'brybbr'
eval(word)
# ybrby
# ryyr
# byb
# rr
# r
#
```